# Prove a partial differentiation equation w.r.t. $g_2,g_3$ for the Weierstrass sigma function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-functions

The [Wolfram Functions Site](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/WeierstrassSigma/13/03/)
gives this partial differentiation equation w.r.t. $g_2,g_3$ for the Weierstrass sigma function

$$   z\frac{\partial \sigma(z; g_2, g_3)}{\partial z}
- 4g_2\frac{\partial \sigma(z; g_2, g_3)}{\partial g_2}
- 6g_3\frac{\partial \sigma(z; g_2, g_3)}{\partial g_3}
- \sigma(z; g_2, g_3) = 0.  $$

I don't get how to use the homogeneity property of sigma to prove this.
Euler's theorem on homogeneous functions does not directly apply since
sigma is not homogeneous in $(z,g_2,g_3)$.

If I assume that the power series expansion of
sigma is a sum of terms of the form (where $c$ is a constant
and $a$ and $b$ are integers)
$\, c g_2^a g_3^b z^{1+4a+6b},\,$ then a simple computation
shows the PDE is true for the term. This reduces the problem
to proving this property of sigma.

Comment: Look up Euler's theorem on homogeneous functions